# When to use Spring Sub-Contexts and when to use Custom-Scopes?

Tags: java, spring, javafx, dependency-injection, spring-framework-beans

I have a JavaFX Application (not a Server-Application!) with many different areas.

These areas have a hierarchy of sub-areas, parts of it reused.

I am using Spring (4.x) for DI and it's getting painful complex.

My question: What is best practice to ensure that I get the right thing (mostly prototype scoped beans) injected into a Sub-Area?

Do I have to implement Custom-Scopes or Sub-Contexts?

---

PS: The Sub-Context solution already worked, but the entire frontend got way too slow from that (about 10 Seconds for building the subcontext)